# How to get the first line of each grouped item in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have a table like this:

ID - Name - Date
1 - Test - 14.09.2021
2 - Test - 14.10.2021

Now I want the row (or ID) grouped by name and ordered by date.

So in MS SQL I would write something like:

```
Select Id from table grouped by Name order by Date
```

But in Oracle it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is your desired result from the data you have shown? You could also perhaps give us a few more data points - preferably in a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk).

Comment: Please read and heed: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Quote from your question:

> So in MS SQL I would write something like:
>
> ```
> Select Id from table grouped by Name order by Date
> ```
>
> But in Oracle it doesn't seem to work

Using a column name in the ORDER BY clause that is not mentioned in the GROUP BY clause seems to be problematic, both with MSSQL and Oracle.  MSSQL may complain about ...

```
Column ... is invalid in the select list 
because it is not contained in either an aggregate function 
or the GROUP BY clause.
```

(see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af34f3b64faee910dfec9b9bd0db9e00))

Oracle's error message is:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

You could use the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function. Example:

Table

```
create table test( id_, name_, date_ )
as
select 1, 'Test1', date '2021-09-14' from dual union all
select 2, 'Test1', date '2021-10-14' from dual union all
select 3, 'Test1', date '2021-11-14' from dual union all
select 4, 'Test2', date '2021-01-10' from dual union all
select 5, 'Test2', date '2021-02-10' from dual union all
select 6, 'Test2', date '2021-03-10' from dual ;
```

Using ROW_NUMBER() - partioning and ordering example

```
select id_, name_, date_
, row_number() over ( partition by name_ order by date_ ) rn_
from test ;

-- output
ID_ NAME_   DATE_       RN_
1   Test1   09/14/2021  1     -- <- first row of the 'Test1' partition
2   Test1   10/14/2021  2
3   Test1   11/14/2021  3
4   Test2   01/10/2021  1     -- <- first row of the 'Test2' partition
5   Test2   02/10/2021  2
6   Test2   03/10/2021  3
```

Final query

```
select *                      -- column names as required!
from (
  select id_, name_, date_
  , row_number() over ( partition by name_ order by date_ ) rn_
  from test
) 
where rn_ = 1
;

-- output
ID_ NAME_   DATE_       RN_
1   Test1   09/14/2021  1
4   Test2   01/10/2021  1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=738ab047ebb86ced017879010fbd7b9d)

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this - since the row_number() over ( partition by name_ order by date_ ) increases the query cost exponentially.

Comment: @AnkitK If you only need the name and the date, you could just use a group by (name) and select name and min( date ).

Maybe you can find something useful in this blog entry, too -
https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-select-the-top-n-rows-per-group-with-sql-in-oracle-database